# Using httprequest::setHeaders() to specify the domain name and httprequest::setUrl() to specify the ip address

Tags: php, http-headers, httprequest

Okay so we have mirroring set up - a central website and the rest are mirrored/cached.

The domain name is the same, eg: domainname.com

but the ip address can change

xxx.xxx.xxx.80 domainname.com - the original domain

xxx.xxx.xxx.81 domainname.com - the mirrored domain, only the ip address is different

I'm writing a routine to check a url on each site.

```
$servers = array('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.80', 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.81');
foreach ($servers as $server) {
    $request = new HttpRequest();
    $request->setUrl($server . '/testpage.php');
    $request->setHeaders(array('host' => 'http://domainname.com'));
    ...
    $request->send();
}
```

But I'm getting 400 "Bad request"

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks, Russ

Answer (score 0):

Removed the http:// and it works!

```
$request->setHeaders(array('host' => 'domainname.com'));
```